# Not able to destroy Cookie on browser close

Tags: javascript, jsp, session, cookies, session-cookies

I am using the JSP to create a cookie , I have to track the cookies value  and run the business logic using cookie value.

I am using the Cookie in following way ;

```
 <%!  Cookie cookie = new Cookie("abc", "true" ); 
  % > 

 cookie.setMaxAge(-1);  // To  Delete the Cookie when browser is closed 
 cookie.setPath("article.jsp"); // To set the path  of the cookie for one page only
 response.addCookie(cookie);

 if(cookie=true){......
      ......
      $(document).ready(function () {
      cookie.setValue("false");
    }

   else{......
      ......
      cookie.setValue("true");
     }
```

This Code seems to be working fine with expected behavior , when i close  browser and open   URL  , in  cookies section  i see the cookie value  present  .

I need to clear the cache and history to destroy the cookie , I doubt if this is the problem that is occurring due to the declaration in the  JSP declaration tag

There could be a way around with declaring the cookies from sevlet the parse in JSP again  to get the value , but I am trying to avoid that and do everything in the JSP

Can any one please explain where in the code the cookie needs to be declared and how ?

Comment: Why cookies? You need to set values on session.

Comment: have you tried `cookie.setMaxAge(0)`? what happens when you do that? What about different browsers?

Comment: Varun  : cookie.setMaxAge(0) is not working i tried it as well.

Comment: Tooraj :   I don't need to use this variable in entire application. I want to initiate  only when user lands on the page so I can instantiate it and start using the cookie value with default value.